# Django admin with multiple inlines of the same model

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm having a problem with prefixes of StackedInlines in admin interface. I'll try to post all the necesary code.

**models.py (brief)**

```
##### Base classes

class BaseItem(models.Model):
    pass

class BaseProvider(PolymorphicModel):
   items = models.ManyToManyField(BaseItem, through="ItemProvided")

class ItemProvided(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(BaseItem)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(BaseProvider)
    price = models.IntegerField()

##### Implementing ones

class Hotel(BaseProvider):
    pass

class Room(BaseItem):
    pass

class Service(BaseItem):
    pass
```

This hierachy reads as follows: a hotel is a provider which can provide either rooms or services.

**admin.py (brief)**

```
#### Creating admin.StackedInline for Rooms

class RoomInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'prefix':'room'})
        super(RoomInlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class HotelRoomInline(admin.StackedInline):
    # This class also filters 'item' choiceField in order to have only ItemProvideds which are rooms
    model = ItemProvided
    formset = RoomInlineFormSet


#### Creating admin.StackedInline for Services

class ServiceInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'prefix':'service'})
        super(ServiceInlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class HotelServiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    # This class also filters 'item' choiceField in order to have only ItemProvideds which are services
    model = ItemProvided
    formset = ServiceInlineFormSet


#### Adding inlines to HotelAdmin and model to admin interface

class HotelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
           HotelRoomInline,
           HotelServiceInline,
           ]

admin.site.register(Hotel, HotelAdmin)
```

With this code I managed to get two separated StackedInlines in admin interface for Hotel model, each of them allowing to select only the proper subset of itemprovideds. Great.

**The problem:** if a have one itemprovided created, in the room's StackedInline, for example; both StackedInlines are populated with the data... prefixes are not well managed...

- Is there anything wrong and obvious in the code I'm not seeing?
- Is there any other good option two obtain the pretended layout in admin interface?

Comment: Do prefixes appear in the templates or are they skipped at all? Also, check if your redefined \_\_init\_\_ is being run at all.

Comment: (I can't check it right now cause I'm not at my computer).... prefix 'room' is applied to the first formset, but the second one also takes 'room' as prefix instead of its own, 'service'.

Answer (score 4):

A better solution than inlines with custom queryset is to use [Proxy Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) with [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets) which adds the default filtering. With that solution you can easily re-use those models outside of the admin:

```
# models.py

class HotelRoomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(HotelRoomManager, self).get_query_set().filter(prefix='room')

class HotelRoom(ItemProvided):
    """ Only ItemProvided with prefix=room """
    objects = HotelRoomManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class HotelServiceManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(HotelServiceManager, self).get_query_set().filter(prefix='service')

class HotelService(ItemProvided):
    """ Only ItemProvided with prefix=service"""
    objects = HotelServiceManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True


#### admin.py

class HotelRoomInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = HotelRoom

class HotelServiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = HotelService

class HotelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
           HotelRoomInline,
           HotelServiceInline,
           ]
```

Comment: I've just tried your solution and it almost works.. but it has shown me a way to solve my problem. Summing up: 1) your solution fixes the problem I was having with prefixes, each formset works ok; 2) I still need to filter the queryset of each inline formset cause it's not in the `itemprovided` where I have to filter (there can be no `itemprovideds` yet) but in `itemprovided__item`.